# plone.app.ldap caches wrong "default user roles" for some users

Tags: ldap, plone

I have an Intranet which I just upgraded from Plone 3.3 to Plone 4.2. Anonymous access is not allowed, Logins are handled by plone.app.ldap. (The ldap server works fine as it already worked nicely for Plone3.3, and is also used successfully for mail and other services)

In the LDAP configuration I set "Default user roles" to "Authenticated,Member" (previously, I accidently had set it to "**Anonymous**,Authenticated,Member" but later on removed the false Anonymous role again)

With some users (about 5 out of about 300) I have the following problem: These 5 users can login but do not see the navigation, they do not the the "Recently Modified" portlet and other things are not visible for them... As it turns out, these 5 users also have the "Anonymous" role assigned next to all the other roles, although I have already disabled it as the default role some days ago.

I did already go to "Caches" tab of the LDAP configuration and clicked "Purge Caches". I also told the users to remove all their Cookies. None did help.

Under the "Caches" tab I noticed that all users with the login problem have as "Cache Type" the value of "authenticated" whereas the user without problem have "anonymous" as "Cache Type". I do not know if this is related but since the problematic users do still have the wrong default user roles - regardless of what I configure as the "Default user roles" for ldap, I thought this might be relevant.

Any hints? I do not have any idea on how to debug this any further.

Comment: Have you tried turning off *page* (not ldap) caching? Make sure this is not a conventional caching problem before worrying too much about ldap configuration.

Comment: Normal caching is turned off. So that's not causing the problem.